# Struts 2 session access issue in my jsp page

Tags: hibernate, session, struts2, ognl

I have a JSP page where i want to display some information from my session   like this way

```
<div>Fonction : <s:property value="%{#session.employe.emploi.nomEmploi}"/>
```

but the problem that it doesn't display anything.

so to explain for you i have an employe class that contains another class emploi, here's the sample code

Employe:

```
public class Employe 
{
  private Long employeId;
  private Emploi emploi;
  private String nom;
  private String prenom;
  private String adresse;
  private String civilite;

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
  @Column(name = "ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
  public Long getEmployeId() {
    return this.employeId;
}

public void setEmployeId(Long employeId) {
    this.employeId = employeId;
}

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "EMP_ID", nullable = false)
    public Emploi getEmploi() {
    return this.emploi;
}

public void setEmploi(Emploi emploi) {
    this.emploi = emploi;
}
    @Column(name = "NOM", nullable = false)
    public String getNom() {
    return this.nom;
}

public void setNom(String nom) {
    this.nom = nom;
}
    @Column(name = "PRENOM", nullable = false)
    public String getPrenom() {
    return this.prenom;
}

public void setPrenom(String prenom) {
    this.prenom = prenom;
}

    @Column(name = "ADRESSE", nullable = false)
    public String getAdresse() {
    return this.adresse;
}

public void setAdresse(String adresse) {
    this.adresse = adresse;
}
    @Column(name = "CIVILITE", nullable = false, length = 20) 
    public String getCivilite() {
    return this.civilite;
}

public void setCivilite(String civilite) {
    this.civilite = civilite;
}
}
```

Emploi:

```
public class Emploi
{
  private Long emploiId;
  private String nomEmploi;
  private Set<Employe> employes = new HashSet<Employe>(0);
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
  @Column(name = "EMP_ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
  public Long getEmploiId() {
    return this.emploiId;
}

public void setEmploiId(Long emploiId) {
    this.emploiId = emploiId;
}
    @Column(name = "NOM_EMPLOI", nullable = false)
public String getNomEmploi() {
    return this.nomEmploi;
}

public void setNomEmploi(String nomEmploi) {
    this.nomEmploi = nomEmploi;
}
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "emploi")
    public Set<Employe> getEmployes() {
    return this.employes;
}

public void setEmployes(Set<Employe> employes) {
    this.employes = employes;
}

}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How did you defined Employe?

Comment: in my jsp page i can access the nom and prenom property like this : <s:property value="%{#session.employe.nom}"/> <s:property value="%{#session.employe.prenom}"/> but for Emploi i don't know what's the problem

Comment: Are you fetching object from database? Maybe your `Emploi` class not being initialized. Check it in your code before putting inside session.

Comment: thank you @AleksandrM for your hint,i have fixed this problem by changing @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY) annotation in the Employe class to @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER) like this :  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)                   @JoinColumn(name = "EMPLOI_ID", nullable = false)
                                                        public Emploi getEmploi() {
  return this.emploi;
 }

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that object is avaialble in session;

using the tag below you will come to know what are the objects that are available in ValueStack.

```
<s:debug/>
```

Outputs the content of the Value Stack.

Another way of doing it is put your project in `devMode` adding the constant below in struts.xml.

```
<constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />
```

> `http://localhost:8080/yourApplication/yourActionName.action?debug=xml`

Comment: but in my jsp page i can display every String in my class employe except the object emploi that i can't access it's properties.

Comment: Assuming emploi is available in session, it possible to post your model structure.

Comment: i have updated the question,there u will find the mode,i think it's a syntax problem becaus i can access every string and integer but the nested object if type Emploi can't be fetched by the session